# WIDCOMM and Android: How do?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

**Disclaimer**: Bluetooth novice question ahead. I'm not trying to troll you with inaccurate / improper use of terms :D

I'm working with a Bluetooth device that communicates using the WIDCOMM stack. In Android, I see that communication is done using [RFCOMM sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.UUID%29) and, so I assume, the RFCOMM stack. How would I allow an Android application using the RFCOMM stack to receive data from a device using the WIDCOMM stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what stack the remote device is using.  You are misunderstanding what widcomm is.  RFCOMM is a standard protocol service that is implemented by all common Bluetooth stack implementations (including widcomm, bluez, android, etc.).  widcomm is just a particular implementation of the stack.  different stacks can communicate because they speak the same standard RFCOMM protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the widcomm stack on the PC .

The Android public APIs uses RFCOMM protocol (which is one of the protocol layers in the Bluetooth stack) it is also called SPP profile commonly.
So both the android stack and widcomm stack will have the same rfcomm/spp profile layers supported.

For PC's you can configure the PC stack to create virtual com port over the SPP (aka RFCOMM) link, to communicate to over this link you can write an application that open this virtual com port and send/receives data - or use an application like hyper terminal to connect to the virtual com port. 
And from the android device your application can use the android RFCOMM apis to connect to and open the rfcomm session with the PC device.
Let me know if this helps..

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't configure the device that communicates via widcomm. That being said, I know for a fact that there is an Android application on the Android Market that has figured out a way to communicate with the particular device I'm using. There therefore has to be some way to do this.